# How to modify a css value in jquery after a substring?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning all,

I want to change the opacity of a color that I get via an attribute.

For this, I get my rgb color that I have set in my data-color attribute : `data-color="rgb(78, 58, 38)"`

Here is my code:

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=skin_color]').change(function () {
    // Get my color to my attribute
    let color = $(this).next().attr('data-color');

    // Extract my color
    let colorExtract = color.substring(0, color.lastIndexOf(')'));

    // Add my opacity to my color
    let newColor = colorExtract + ' / 0.6)';

    // debug
    console.log(newColor);

    // Add css with my color opacity
    $(this).next().css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 0px 5px ' + newColor);
});
```

In my debugging console, I have a string with the desired value, but it does not apply. Anyone have any idea why this is not working?

**EDIT (SOLUTION):**

I didn't pay attention, but there is no coma when I add an opacity. I just had to add `string.replace (/,/g, '')` to cut out my color again.

Comment: you didn't write the code `next()` element which you are referencing, but if you are changing style of current eleemnt use `$(this).css()` and remove `next()`

Comment: No precisely, I modify the element after a radio input.